# How to remove the implicit SEQUENCE on ID field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, primary-key, sequence

I've seen we can avoid using a SEQUENCE on the object's ID by doing this:

```
create_table :table_name, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :id
  t.timestamps
end
```

But, if my table is already created and I want to remove the "CREATE SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq" from the schema, how can I do this without dropping the table? If impossible it will be ok I guess but I did not want to loose my table content.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll have to use raw SQL to do this. Something like the following:

```
def up
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "DROP SEQUENCE table_name_id_seq"
end
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-dropsequence.html

Comment: DROP SEQUENCE place_type_dictionaries_id_seq CASCADE, had to use CASCADE